# Property prices in a rotating space habitat?

Tags: economy, space-colonization

In a rotating space habitat, something like a [Bernal Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernal_sphere), the 'equator' would have stronger gravity than the location closer to the 'poles'. If people living there have to buy their own house (and land), which part of the sphere would have higher prices and why?

I imagine the lower equatorial part might have lower prices simply because it's the most common space available. The space near the poles with weaker gravity might be more expensive because there's less of it and rich old people with weaker bodies might enjoy being there.

But what do you think?

Comment: Lots of close votes here.  Any reasons people want to post?

Comment: It might all be a worthless hub of scum and villainy. Why does it exist? Does it have industry? Has it been maintained? Etc etc. There's more to house prices than local gravity.

Comment: One can safely assume it has industry (or is otherwise self-sustainable) if _people buy their own houses_.

Comment: I fail to see how the answer saying "depends on location and surroundings rather than on gravity" is an _opinion_.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends what the space habitat is for.**

You can have a very nice lakeside property.  It seems like people would pay a lot to live there.  But it is next to a working harbor, or may contain a working harbor - lots of workers coming and going, big machines working day and night.

The famous three things that determine real estate prices: location, location, location.  Gravity is interesting but physical aspects of the properties will matter a lot too.  Is it next to a reservoir - that could be nice.  Does it abut a working spaceport or transportation hub?  If there are kids here, are there good schools?  Is the unsavory alien quarter nearby?

Why does this thing exist in the first place?  Is it purely residential with people commuting to jobs?  Is it a retirement community strictly for weak old people?

Gravity is an interesting factor but many others come into play.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty opinion based, but I'd imagine the equatorial places would be higher demand because it's more like Earth - while the novelty of being in a low gravity area might be good, you wouldn't want to live there.

Rich old people with weaker bodies might *enjoy* being there, but probably only for short periods of time. To live there would be very bad for their health because muscles degrade in weightlessness through non use (astronauts on the IIS for long periods of time have to work out for a few hours a day just to keep their muscles from deteriorating). That is especially bad for older people.

OTOH the human body is built for Earth like conditions and so would probably be best that people lived there.

Maybe a "low gravity park" could be built near the poles where people would visit for recreation, but I would doubt anyone would want to live there.

Comment: Low gravity is also beneficial for heavy industry/assembly lines, if there are any.